# Explain the output of this program

Tags: c++, class

I can't figure out how this works, the code is really complicated because it is for a programming class I'm in. I can't seem to get the program's output when I work it through manually, it is the practice test for our final next week, I wouldn't cheat on a test, the professor gave us the program and the output, I just don't understand why that is the output..:

```
class FinalExam
{
private:

   int This;
   int That;

public:

   FinalExam(int, int);
   void One(int);
   int  Two(int);
};

FinalExam :: FinalExam(int A = 3, int B = 5)
{
   This = A;
   That = B;
}

void FinalExam :: One(int A)
{
   This --;
   That = A;
}

int FinalExam :: Two(int A) // Two gets the int 8
{
   int Scrap; 
   Scrap = This + That - A; // 5 + 2 - 8 = -1???? 
   return Scrap;
}

main()
{

   FinalExam Block;
   FinalExam Chunk(6, 7);

   Block.One(2);

   cout << Block.Two(3) 
        << '\n'
        << Chunk.Two(8); //I get lost on this 8, It should go to "Two"
}
```

And the output is:

```
1

5
```

I have looked at this for about an hour and I don't understand.

Comment: Reformated at http://ideone.com/kyIgh

Comment: Class "Final Exam"... looks like this may be a test question. I don't know if it's ethical for us to help you out.

Comment: I don't get it...going through your code manually the output looks correct. But this looks like an exam, so yeah.

Comment: it is the practice test for our final next week, I wouldn't cheat on a test, the professor gave us the program and the output, I just don't understand why that is the output...

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: Ya rly :) If my professor caught me posting a question from one of his practice exams here, he'd hit me over the head with a big ole' bag of abstraction. If Tanner Ewing makes some effort to explain what he's comprehended, we can help. Otherwise this question shouldn't be here.

Comment: @TannerEwing - tell us the steps you're going through to show us why you think the results you're getting at manually don't agree with the output you see. I followed the code and got `1` and `5`.

Comment: Whoever wrote this code should be strung up for having a member variable "This", which is different from keyword "this".

Comment: @TannerEwing: When you have an answer you like, you should mark one you like best with the Checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FinalExam Block;  // Not passing any arguments to the constructor. In that case, 
                  // default argument values are taken. So, This = 3, That = 5


Block.One (2);     // This = 2; That = 2
                   // Because This is decremented and That is assigned the value
                   // passed to the method which is 2.


cout << Block.Two (3) ;  // 2 + 2 - 3 = 1 which is returned and is printed.
```

Similarly try the second one.

Comment: When i try the second one I end up with 5 + 2 - 8 = -1  I should be getting 5??

Comment: @TannerEwing, `6 + 7  - 8 = 5`

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a line-by-line breakdown:**

**1** `FinalExam Block;`
Uses the constructor with default values, so `Block.This` = **3**, and `Block.That` = **5**.

---

**2** `FinalExam Chunk(6, 7);`
Uses the constructor, specifying values, so `Chunk.This` = **6** and `Chunk.That` = **7**.

---

**3** `Block.One(2);`
Decrements `Block.This` (3 ==> 2), and assigns `Block.That` = **2** (was previously 5).

---

**4** `Block.Two(3)`
returns `Block.This` + `Block.That`-3 ==> 2+2-3 ==> 1, which is output.

---

**5** `Chunk.Two(8)` 
returns `Chunk.This` + `Chunk.That` - 8 ==> 6+7-8 ==> 5, which is output.

---

**Q.E.D. the output is "1 \n 5"**

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of what's happening in the comments between the lines.

```
int main(int, char**) {
   FinalExam Block;
   // At this point ..
   // Block.This = 3;
   // Block.That = 5
   FinalExam Chunk(6, 7);
   // Chunk.This = 6
   // Chunk.That = 7
   Block.One(2);
   // Block.One decrement's This and assigns 2 to That so ..
   // Block.This = 2
   // Block.That = 2
   std::cout << Block.Two(3)
        // Block.Two(3) returns the result of this calculation
        // This + That - 3
        // This and That are both 2 at this point so..
        // 2 + 2 - 3 == 1
        // It returns 1 and prints out '1'
        << std::endl
        << Chunk.Two(8);
        // Chunk's This and That are 6 and 7 respectively so ..
        // cout << 6 + 7 - 8 == 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll notice that we're creating two objects of type FinalExam called Block and Chunk.

Block:
since block wasn't passed any values via the parameter, it will take on the default values which come from this code block:

```
    FinalExam :: FinalExam(int A = 3, int B = 5)
{
   This = A;
   That = B;
}
```

so This = 3 and That = 5

The next line that effects Block is:

```
Block.One(2);
```

which refers to this *code block*:

```
void FinalExam :: One(int A)
{
   This --;
   That = A;
}
```

so This = 2 (This = This - 1 or This = 3 - 1) 
and That = 2 (That = A = 2(passed by value in parameters)

The last line effecting Block is:

```
cout << Block.Two(3)
```

which refers to this code block:

```
int FinalExam :: Two(int A) // Two gets the int 8
{
   int Scrap; 
   Scrap = This + That - A; // 5 + 2 - 8 = -1???? 
   return Scrap;
}
```

so we create a new integer called Scrap = 1 (This + That - A or 2 + 2 - 3(passed by value))

Chunk:
the first line that refers to Chunk is:

```
FinalExam Chunk(6, 7);
```

this set A = 6 and B = 7 
and because of this code block:

```
FinalExam :: FinalExam(int A = 3, int B = 5)
{
   This = A;
   That = B;
}
```

This = 6 and That = 7 (This = A = 6 and That = B = 7)

and finally, we have this line:

```
Chunk.Two(8);
```

which refers to this code block:

```
int FinalExam :: Two(int A) // Two gets the int 8
{
   int Scrap; 
   Scrap = This + That - A; // 5 + 2 - 8 = -1???? 
   return Scrap;
}
```

A is set to 8 since we passed it by value through parameters
and Scrap = 5 (b + 7 - 8 or This + That - A)

Output:
We output Scrap from Block which is 1
and create a new line
and output Scrap from Chunk which is 5

Hope this helps, leave a comment if you have any additional questions